# SQL Server can't find backup file in Docker container

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker on Windows to run Microsoft SQL Server inside a Linux container. Until a couple of weeks ago I just mounted a folder on my host machine into the container (via a docker-compose file) and ran a `RESTORE` command in SQL Server to restore a database backup from a file inside the mounted folder.

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    sqlserver:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest"
        environment:
            - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
            - "SA_PASSWORD=********"
            - "MSSQL_COLLATION=Latin1_General_CI_AS"
            - "TZ=Europe/Berlin"

        ports:
            - 14333:1433
        networks:
            - ssnet
        volumes:
            - ./mssql/backup:/var/opt/mssql/backup
networks:
    ssnet:
        driver: bridge
```

---

**UPDATE**

And this is the `RESTORE` command

```
IF(db_id(N'MyDatabase') IS NULL)
BEGIN
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDatabase.bak' WITH MOVE 'MyDatabase_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase.mdf', MOVE 'MyDatabase_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase_1.ldf';
END
```

**/UPDATE**

---

That worked. Until it didn't. The host folder is still mounted under `/var/opt/mssql/backup/` and when I open a shell in the container I can see the file where it should be. Permissions seem ok (rwx for root, rx for everybody else) but SQL Server insists that it can't find the file (neither via the `RESTORE` command nor the dialog from SQL Server Management Studio) although it can see the mounted folder quite alright.

I thought the culprit was a recent update of Docker as their release notes suggested there were certain changes to how volumes are mounted on Windows but a downgrade did not fix the problem. When I move the backup file from the mounted folder somewhere else in the container filesystem (e.g. `/var/opt/mssql/`) SQL Server can see the file again. Permissions are identical.

I already deleted the container (several times), uninstalled Docker and danced around my computer on the full moon. Nothing worked.

Any ideas how I can fix that without having to resort to moving the file after starting the container?

Comment: Oh, you forgot to wave the dead chicken. Seriously, though, can you edit your question to include the restore command you're trying and the exact error message it responds with?

Comment: Is it possible your docker-compose.yml file changed recently? I hit an issue today with Docker on a macOS machine where the `volumes` under `services` weren't recognized until I bumped the file version up to at least `3.2`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the `docker-compose.yml` is versioned in a Git repository and didn't change at the time.